# How do graduate admissions committees view published undergraduate research papers?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, computer-science, research-undergraduate

When an undergraduate student choses to publish a research paper(as well as submit it to conferences) out of doing research with a professor, the research paper may be viewed differently for admissions into academia as well as employment fields(like Computer Science).

How do both views differ & is it more valued in academia than for employment?

Comment: This being Academia.SE, people on this site probably won't be able to tell you much about how they are viewed for employment in industry.  You might want to take that part out of your question.

Answer (score 1):

For any job, relevant experience tends to be one of the most important factors.

Having a published paper on your CV will typically be more important in academia.  Jobs in academia are likely to involve contributing to academic papers, while (most) industry jobs do not.

A paper is still a nice accomplishment to have on your CV.  But for an industry job such as a software developer, the question will be "Can you code?"  It is possible that a computer science graduate has a whole heap of academic accomplishments, yet has no idea how to write software (I have encountered such candidates).

One important point is: **tailor your CV to emphasize the right things for the field.**

For example, if you did a computer science project that involved writing some software to do something novel, and then published on it, you would highlight different things on your CV depending on the type of job you were going for.

- For academia, you would probably emphasize the novel methods and academic output.
- For industry, you may want to highlight the software development skills you employed.